# Login form doesn't start user session

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I'm using Devise and Bootstrap in my Rails app

In the Bootstrap navbar i have this login form:

```
<form class="navbar-form pull-right">
    <% if current_user %>
        <b><%= link_to current_user.name, current_user %></b>
        <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
    <% else %>  
        <input class="span2" type="text" placeholder="Email">
        <input class="span2" type="password" placeholder="Password">
        <button type="submit" class="btn"><%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %></button>

        <button type="submit" class="btn"><%= link_to "Register", new_user_registration_path %></button>
    <% end %>
</form>
```

If I enter the email/pass and hit "sign in", then the page refreshes, but the user session doesn't start (the user hasn't been logged in). Am I doing something wrong in this form?

I can sign in using the Devise `/sign_in` page but i want to be able to do so aswell in my nav bar :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form isn't posting to anything, those link_to tags aren't really doing anything. 
Links aren't the same as inputs.

Instead you need a form like this:

```
<% if current_user %>
   <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
<% else %>  
   <%= form_for("user", :url => new_user_session_path, :html => { :class => "navbar-form pull-right"}) do |f|%>
     <%= f.text_field :email, :class=>"span2"%>
     <%= f.text_field :password, :class=>"span2"%>
     <%= f.submit "Sign in", :class => "btn"%>
   <% end %>
   <%= link_to "Register", new_user_registration_path, :class => "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

You'll need a separate form for registration, I suggest simply linking to another registration page.